# Relay does not turn on when using a 2.5A 12V power supply

Tags: power-supply, relay, inrush-current

I have a relay that I am using for a project. The relay datasheet is [here](https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=showdoc&DocId=Catalog%20Section%7F5-1773450-5_sec7_EV200A%7F1120%7Fpdf%7FEnglish%7FENG_CS_5-1773450-5_sec7_EV200A_1120.pdf%7F1-1618002-1).

I am using a 12V DC 2.5A power supply to supply power to the relay above, [datasheet](https://www.mornsun-power.com/html/pdf/URB4812YMD-30WR3.html). From the datasheet, however, I saw that the inrush current is at 3.8A. However because this is inrush and not a steady-state (which is 0.13A @ 12V DC), I thought a 2.5A power supply will be enough to power it.

However this is not the case, the relay does not engage. I then tried a 12V 3.3A power supply and it now works, [datasheet](https://www.tracopower.com/products/ten40e.pdf).

So does this mean I need to spec the power supply to the inrush current even though the inrush only last a few milliseconds?

[image]

Comment: Could you add a capacitor to supply the inrush current? Without a circuit diagram for the area in question, I can't say where to place it.

Comment: Could you energise the relay coil with the unregulated input voltage? Isolation, if required, from the rest of the circuit could be maintained by using an optocoupler for the signal.

Comment: 3.8A for 130ms is about half a coulomb. That gives you a good idea of the capacitor required : if you can tolerate 1V of sag, half a Farad should be enough. (Getting the PSU to start with 0.5F across its output may be an issue though)

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yes I can add a cap, but I will have to add it so it is as close as possible to the relay.

Comment: The power supply is only specified to 2000 uF. 0.5 F at 12 V is about the size of a milk bottle

Comment: What is the input voltage to the voltage regulator? If it is within the voltage rating of the relay coil then you do not need to use the voltage regulator to supply the relay coil current.

Answer (score 2):

I guess your power supply has foldback protection behaviour. A short too high current peak drops the output voltage and it doesn't return before the load resistance has grown high enough. Constant current -type protection scheme doesn't have that problem.

An advanced power supply can have a switch to select which behaviour is in use to protect the PSU against overload.

The specs for low cost mass produced stuff purchased from webshops can be very loose. I guess you have no documentation of the overload protection behaviour nor the recovery action for your problematic power supply.

ADD: The relay inrush peak happens when the coil current has risen high enough to accelerate the moving parts, not before and not a long time after the moving parts have reached their new positions. If the voltage tries to return a new inrush peak can occur. It's as well possible that the voltage stays low because the foldback is never released. Only measurements tell, there's no details printed of the shutdown and recovery actions, I guess.

Comment: Where about in the datasheet will tell me this?

Comment: I can say it only after seeing the datasheet. A possible answer: Nothing is mentioned.

Comment: The datasheets for both power supplies is in post, text hyperlinks (datasheets).

Comment: @JoeyB The datasheet mentions output short-circuit overcurrent protection, which could mean foldback.

Comment: There's nothing except "automatic recovery". The inrush happens when the relay works a short time as running electric motor. The running time is about 0,13 seconds - no more,  because the movement distance is not very long. The protection in the PSU can well be made to react that soon. When the power supply tries to recover the movement can start again and cause a new voltage drop due overcurrent. The other PSU probably doesn't try to be especially fast to pull the voltage down in case of overload. No specs also there. Check if the 1st PSU makes repeating retries or does Vout stay low.

Comment: @user287001 sure I can test that, however what parameter in the datasheet tells me this part "When the power supply tries to recover the movement can start again and cause a new voltage drop due to overcurrent. The other PSU probably doesn't try to be especially fast to pull the voltage down in case of overload"?

Comment: @user287001 is it called "Transient Response" which is found in both datasheets? Okay they both have response time of 250 microseconds

Comment: @JoeyB transient response is what happens when the load current grows suddenly 25% but still staying in allowed range. Your case was short overload.

Comment: @JoeyB The recovery trial is when the PSU attempts the advertised automatic recovery. The PSU datasheet does't describe what subactions that attempt contains. The new movement in the relay is not at all PSU's behaviour, The relay seller has got your money for the ability of the relay to act when it gets enough voltage and it gets when the voltage returns.

Comment: @user287001 Since I see there is not much info in this datasheet, I am correct in saying I should just use a power supply rated for the inrush current of the relay, so rather just use a 12V 4A power supply?

Comment: That should work. But to be sure, the PSU cannot have other loads.

Comment: @user287001 there is another 12V load but this only draws around 300mA max, so 4A should be more than okay.

Comment: What it draws just when the voltages are switched ON?

Comment: @user287001 by the way, by having two URB_YMD-30WR3 in parallel, so 5A will not do much because the voltage will start to drop due to overcurrent, correct?

Comment: @user287001 oh that 300mA is the peak (during start up), it drops to steady-state around 153mA.

Comment: Parallel PSUs to increase the current capability is a fatal idea if the supplies are not specially designed for it. Do not try it if it's not specified. The voltage controls must have a common brain and goal to make it work. All burden is taken by the one which has a little lower output voltage. In overload conditions there can occur chaotic oscillations.

Comment: @user287001 now I am confused! I tested another relay with the 12V 2.5A supply and it turned on, better yet I also had a 12V 1.6A DC/DC (https://www.meanwellusa.com/upload/pdf/SKA20/SKA20-spec.pdf) laying around and it still turned on, what is going here... How can this relay vary it coil impedance this drastically. I am so confused!

Comment: Check with a storage oscilloscope what there actually happens (=current, voltage) otherwise all is guessing. the relay coil has resistance, inductance and  a moment it also acts like a motor which draws power to accelerate. All factors can be important.

Answer (score 1):

> So does this mean I need to spec the power supply to the inrush current even though the inrush only lasts a few milliseconds?

YES.

The alternative is to have a battery and trickle charger that meets these specs or an expensive Ultracap that can store the same amount of energy.

**Opinion**

Interpreting the  Specs:

Inrush Current (Max.) 3.8A from 9 to 36V

- This means DCR =  2.4 Ohms (=9/3.8) to  9.5 Ohms (=36/3.8)

  - it may have a relay-switched series R (most likely) or a passive NTC inrush current limiter (ICL) or an active current limiter.

Holding Current (Avg .) 0.13A @ 12V,  0.07A @ 24V

- **This implies incremental impedance is negative.**  Rin=ΔV/ΔI= (24-12)/(0.07-0.13)=-200 ohms but constant power.  **P= 1.68 W** (12 V * 0.13 A) &  **P = 1.56 W** (24 * 0.07 A)   Yet inrush is 36W to 136W.

So to benefit from this power-saving device, you need to ensure you can guarantee the surge power.  (It is designed this way to switch fast but not burn out)

You must guarantee a design that is cost-effective but will not fail.

[image]  From your datasheet This is not a simple relay, rather, it's a smart "contactor" (high current relay).

Comment: Thanks, I was designing it to accommodate the steady-state current of 0.13A

Comment: now I am confused! I tested another relay with the 12V 2.5A supply and it turned on, better yet I also had a 12V 1.6A DC/DC (meanwellusa.com/upload/pdf/SKA20/SKA20-spec.pdf) laying around and it still turned on, what is going here... How can this relay vary it coil impedance this drastically. I am so confused!

Comment: This is not a simple relay, rather, it's a smart relay with non-specific switched resistance tolerances for minimum.. only maximum current

Comment: What do you mean by smart (in terms of powering it)?

Comment: Why would a 1.6A DC PSU even work for this contactor but the first one I tried?

Comment: It has a negative impedance , not a fixed resistance.  (meaning other circuits involved to limit current)

Comment: Can you explain this a bit more "meaning other circuits involved to limet current"

Comment: Reverse engineering with hypothetical solutions is beyond the scope of this question. But it can be an active circuit for example to control these characteristics. or a time delay relay with series R and snubbers

Comment: I do not mind hypothetical solutions because I do not know what questions to ask, so by reading these solutions I can understand and test my side to confirm and then I can ask more accurate questions that have specific solutions.

Comment: just imagine there is some timer relay to insert a series resistance somehow, somewhere inside to limit current after it closes.  Using a variable lab power supply may give more clues.

Comment: Just trying to figure out how will this (your comment above, since the "series resistance" appears after the inrush/contactor close) explains why the second contactor turns on with 1.6A while the first contactor only turns on with a 3.3A supply? BTW this is the contactor I have https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mqEQHe9qlKc the internals

Comment: I guess you need to define your test methods and results with more details to put into my crystal ball,  lol

Comment: Lol I see, I guess what I am saying is what are you trying to achieve by doing what you said in your comment?

Comment: The circuit needs to satisfy the datasheet specs. How it is done is less important. But I see you are curious.

Comment: OK Here's a dumb solution in slow motion https://tinyurl.com/y3ycfj84  press reset.  or switch.  Can you figure out what's happening?

Comment: yes, I do. So the solenoid contactor's coil gets charged through the 2A relay N/C contactor since it goes to the ground. Then when the solenoid's coil is charged to close/open the contactor the 2A relay then turns on and is now in the N/O position. But the solenoid contactor coil is now in series with the 180-ohm resistor reducing the current needed to power the solenoid contactor's coil. Is this correct?

Comment: If I am understanding this correctly. The contactors I have will have different inrush current values. Clearly, the first one needs a much higher current to startup than the second contactor. I can confirm this by current limiting my power supply and keeping a constant voltage and testing the two contactors. However, what we can know for certain is the worse case scenario is that I will need 3.8A of current to turn on any contactor with 100% certainty. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes That's what max specs mean, yet the test methods are not given as the storage capacitance nor the velocity or time delay of the contactor and if they are performing as expected. So the specs are rather thin and do not specify the duration or product of Amp-seconds or energy required. So it is up to you do more due diligence to sample more products if this is important with all the parameters not given that are important to you.